# PyMatching.Matching.decode() returns incorrectly sized array

Tags: error-correction, stim, pymatching

I have having trouble getting the `decode(...)` function for a `pymatching.Matching` object to return an array of an appropriate size. Instead of returning an array with the number of qubits in a code, the function returns an array containing a single 0 or 1. The decode function seems to work with the `pymatching` tutorial notebooks, but I am unable to get the result on my own. The interesting thing is that when using the new `decode_to_matched_dets_array(...)` function, I get the matched pairs. Below is an example of what I'm talking about using a stim generated circuit:

```
# Inputs
distance = 9
reps = 9
shots = 1
noise = 1e-2*np.ones(4)

# Define circuit and matching graph
circuit = stim.Circuit.generated(
    'repetition_code:memory',
    rounds=reps,
    distance=distance,
    after_clifford_depolarization=noise[0],
    after_reset_flip_probability=noise[1],
    before_measure_flip_probability=noise[2],
    before_round_data_depolarization=noise[3]
)
error_model = circuit.detector_error_model(decompose_errors=True)
match = pm.Matching.from_detector_error_model(error_model)

# Sample results
sampler = circuit.compile_detector_sampler()
syndromes, observables = sampler.sample(shots, separate_observables=True)

# Decode Results
int_syndromes = [int(det) for det in syndromes[0]]
pairs = match.decode_to_matched_dets_array(int_syndromes)
corrections = match.decode(int_syndromes)

print('corrections:\n',corrections)
print('pairs:\n',pairs)
```

Would output something like

```
corrections:
 [0]
pairs:
 [[18 20]
 [57 65]
 [58 59]
 [62 63]]
```

when I would expect `corrections` to show an array containing 0s and 1s of length 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit you're generating only contains one logical observable, and pymatching is predicting whether that single logical observable is flipped or not. **One logical observable therefore one output bit.**

Pymatching doesn't predict whether each physical measurement or each physical qubit is individually flipped. This maximizes how fast it is, and avoids reporting information that in most contexts you do not actually need. Plus, keep in mind that pymatching is never told the circuit. It only gets the match graph. The match graph doesn't say how many measurements there are or how many qubits there are, it instead talks about how many detectors there are and how many error mechanisms there are.

In principle what you want is a bit like editing the Stim circuit so that there is one logical observable per data qubit instead of one logical observable total. Ironically, Stim has safety features to prevent this! The issue is that these single-qubit observables are individually unpredictable, meaning they can't be trivially used for automatic benchmarking. Normally this means the circuit contains a show-stopping mistake, like you ran the Z observable the wrong way along the patch. I'll add your question to the "should I add an `allow_gauge_observables` option to `stim.Circuit.detector_error_model`" pile.)

Comment: Thanks for the context Craig!